# $\overline{G} = \mathbb{R}$ iff every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $G$

Tags: real-analysis

I think one way to show that,

for a given $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the closure of $G$ ($\overline{G}$) is $\mathbb{R}$ iff every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $G$,

is to consider dense sets. In other words, I think the string

$\overline{G} = \mathbb{R}$ iff $G$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ iff every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $G$

does the job.

But is there any alternative proof? Can the claim be proved directly?

Comment: Isn't your "proof" just restating the theorem? I'm not sure I understand the question, otherwise. As for whether or not alternative proofs exist, yes, but probably most of them are just variations of using definitions.

Comment: There are almost infinitely many equivalent definitions for $\overline{G}$ so please add a definition for every notion you describes.